# GIt Delete local repository without the data

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I deleted a repository from the remote git.
However the project is still connected to my local git repository.

1. How do I remove the project from local git repository from Eclipse?
2. How do I delete the local git repository from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [deleting the git repo from the EGit Repositories view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Removing_Repositories)

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/ec/Egit-0.10-DeleteRepository.png]

It will let you decide if you want to delete the repository's working directory with the projects contained in the repository from the Eclipse workspace.

Even less dangerous would be simply [Removing a Repository from the Repositories View](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Removing_a_Repository_from_the_Repositories_View), before removing the project from Eclipse workspace.

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/b/bd/Egit-0.10-RemoveRepository.png]

That way, the underlying git repo still has its local git history.